# Teradata: Filling forward rows into nulls

Tags: sql, teradata

I have some data in Tera Data and am looking to fill the rows forward, from the "what I have" column to what is in the "what I want" column. I am hoping all you need is the information in the what I have column in order to satisfy it.

| EVENT | EVENT_NUM | WHAT I HAVE | WHAT I WANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | NULL | 1 |
| C | 3 | NULL | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| D | 2 | NULL | 2 |
| F | 3 | NULL | 2 |
| B | 4 | NULL | 2 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 2 | NULL | 3 |
| D | 3 | NULL | 3 |
| C | 4 | NULL | 3 |
| F | 5 | NULL | 3 |

Comment: Is there an id/sequence column too?

Comment: You need to explain the logic for populating your derived column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.